# When the page is refreshed in Flutter, the information in Firestore appears more than once

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

**I have a page like in the image and when the card under the name 'Games' is clicked in the middle,**

[image]

**I am running a showDiolog method.**

```
Future<String?> openDialog() => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Games',
              style: loginText,
            ),
          ),
          content: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          actions: [TextButton(onPressed: submit, child: Text('Save'))],
        ),
      );

  void submit() {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(controller.text);
  }
```

When the save text is clicked, it communicates with the firebase database once again, refreshes the page and shows me the same user twice as in the image below.

[image]

**The function I use when creating a user's properties**

```
 Future createUser(Profiles profile) async {
    final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles').doc();
    profile.id = docUser.id;

    final json = profile.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
```

**and this is my button using the function I created.**

```
LoginButton(
          onPressed: () {
            signUp();
            final user = Profiles(
                id: id.v1(),
                email: email.text.trim(),
                gender: selectedGender == 1 ? 'Erkek' : 'Kadın',
                name: name.text.trim(),
                username: username.text.trim());

            createUser(user);
          }, // signUp,
        )
```

**The class I created named Profiles that contains the properties of the user.**

```
   class Profiles {
  String id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String gender;
  final String email;

  Profiles(
      {required this.id,
      required this.email,
      required this.gender,
      required this.name,
      required this.username});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'email': email,
        'username': username
      };

  static Profiles fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Profiles(
      id: json['id'],
      email: json['email'],
      gender: json['gender'],
      name: json['name'],
      username: json['username']);
}
```

**Finally, here is the code where I get the data uploaded to Firestore.**

```
 User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  List<String> docIDs = [];
 getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profiles')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: user?.email)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
              docIDs.add(element.reference.id);
            }));
  }
FutureBuilder(
          future: getDocId(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docIDs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        GetUsername(documentId: docIDs[index]))),
                        GetGender(documentId: docIDs[index]),
```

**GetUsername widget, one of the data it get from the database 2 times**

```
  class GetUsername extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;
  const GetUsername({super.key, required this.documentId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              '${data['username']}',
              style: loginText,
            ),
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u just need to synchronise the code a little bit like,

```dart
   User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
   List<String> docIDs = [];
   getDocId() async {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profiles').where('email', isEqualTo:user?.email)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
           docIDs = [];
           snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
              docIDs.add(element.reference.id);
         })});
   }
   FutureBuilder(
          future: getDocId(),
          builder: (context, snapShot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docIDs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
```

Comment: I get an error. The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'AsyncSnapshot<Object?>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: let me edit my code wait.

Comment: check now. just add another then( (_)=>.....)

Comment: I get an error. The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'List<String>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Comment: Just edited a little bit. check now

Comment: Yes it worked. Could you please tell me what this minor change makes it different from my code?

Comment: ur FutureBuilder getting called multiple times & its adding data to each time to the list (docIDs). When u already have 1 data in the list(docIDs) and u add another one ur FutureBuilder getDocId(..){...} method gets called & it adds 2 data in the list (fetched from web). Now ur list have 3 data's[bcz u have 2 data's in the web & ur list had 1 previous data]. So to overcome the duplication u need empty ur list whenever u add a data